# Apostol proof of subset openness in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

The theorem goes as follows:

Let $(S, d)$ be a metric subspace of $(M, d)$, and let $Y \subseteq S$. Then Y is closed if and only if $Y = B \cap S$ for some set $B$ which is closed in $M$.

The Apostol proof of the "if" direction goes as follows:

If $Y = B \cap S$, where $B$ is closed in $M$, then $B = M - A$, where $A$ is open in $M$. Then:

$$Y = S \cap B = S \cap (M - A) = S - A$$

from where Apostol says: "hence Y is closed in S". Page 62 of Mathematical Analysis Edition 2.

How does Apostol jump from "$S - A$" to "$Y$ is closed in $S$"?

IMHO, $A$ is open in $M$, not in $S$. Thus, the implication of open/closed-flipping ("S" is closed in $M$, if $M - S$ is open) does not work for $S - A$ from the outset. So, seems like a big leap of logic here, or incorrect proof, or I am missing something.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: @Bungo, $S - A = S \cap (M - A)$ indeed, basic set theory. But how does "closed in $S$" follow from "the intersection of $S$ with a closed subset of $M$"?

Comment: @Bungo, he defines it as stated: "$S$ is closed in $M$, if $M - S$ is open".

Comment: OK, so $Y$ is closed in $S$, if $S-Y$ is open in $S$. How does he define "open in $S$" when $S$ is a subspace of $M$?

Comment: @Bungo, there is a similar theorem, as this one: it states that some $X$ is open in metric subspace $S$ iff $X = A \cap S$ and $A$ is some open set in $M$. Otherwise, he does not define "open in a metric subspace" in any way different from normal metric space I gave you above.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove my extraneous comments above and write up a quick answer. I suggest editing your question to mention the theorem you just cited.

Comment: Btw, you mention $C$ twice in your question, but I think it should be $S$ in both cases.

Comment: @Bungo, I fixed it: C = Latex "\Cap" - editing artifact :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Apostol has provided the following theorem, which I'll refer to as **Theorem 1**:

> If $(S,d)$ is a metric subspace of $(M,d)$, then $X \subseteq S$ is open in $S$ if and only if $X = A \cap S$, where $A$ is an open subset of $M$.

Let's prove the closed set version:

> If $(S,d)$ is a metric subspace of $(M,d)$, then $Y \subseteq S$ is closed in $S$ if and only if $Y = B \cap S$, where $B$ is a closed subset of $M$.

First, the "if" part that you asked about in your question:

Suppose $Y = B \cap S$, where $B$ is a closed subset of $M$. Thus we can write $B = M - A$, where $A$ is an open subset of $M$. Then

$$Y = B \cap S = (M-A) \cap S = S - A$$

Consequently,
$$S - Y = S - (S - A) = S \cap A$$
so by **Theorem 1**, $S - Y$ is open in $S$. Hence $Y$ is closed in $S$.

---

Now, for the "only if" part:

Suppose that $Y$ is a closed subset of $S$. If we define $X = S - Y$, then $X$ is an open subset of $S$. Hence by **Theorem 1**, we can express $X = S \cap A$ where $A$ is an open subset of $M$. Thus
$$Y = S - X = S - (S \cap A) = S \cap (M - A)$$
Since $M-A$ is a closed subset of $M$, we may set $B = M-A$.

Comment: Thx a lot! I have been staring at it for quite a while, could not figure if I missed some step. Seems like there was quite a jump in the proof (use of the first theorem) I could not pick myself.